# Django query to get objects which share the same foreignkey field

Tags: django

i have 2 models: meeting and attendee

attendee has a foreignkey field back to meeting

```
class Meeting(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    venue = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

class Attendee(models.Model):
    meeting = models.ForeignKey(Meeting)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

I want to get a list of meetings where 2 users are attending the same meeting?

so say I have 2 users bill and ben.

```
   ben = User.objects.get(username='ben')
   bill = User.objects.get(username='bill')
```

What query would I need to run to get meeting record where bill and ben were attendees?

```
meetings = Meeting.objects.filter(????)
```

Comment: Deleted my answer, can't think of what to do right now. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this solution seems to work although I'm not sure if its the best way to do it

```
meeting = Meeting.objects.filter(attendee__user=bill)
meeting = meeting.filter(attendee__user=ben)
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can use [Q](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects):

```
from django.db.models import Q
meetings = Meeting.objects.filter(Q(attendee__user=ben) & Q(attendee__user=bill))
```

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
meetings = Meeting.objects.filter(attendee__user__in = [ben, bill])
```

where ben and bill are user objects

Comment: hmm, come to think of it i think this query wouldn't differentiate if both were part of the meeting, ill check for better solution

Comment: yes just checked and it does bring back meetings that either bill or ben had attended not both